# Async task library that automatically hooks into Activity lifecycle methods

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous, android-lifecycle

I'm looking for a library that will simplify performing async operations (network requests, heavy parsing of data, etc.) and that its callback will be called in the right time without me needing to workaround it.

I'll give a few examples:

1. Fragment transactions - if I want to perform a fragment transaction when an async task completes then I need to make sure that the activity is in the "post resumed" state, otherwise I get the infamous *IllegalStateException*. This means two things: first of all in the async task callback I need to check that the activity is post-resumed. Second, if it's not post-resumed then I need to set a member variable on the activity that once *onPostResume* or *onResumeFragments* is called then I'll perform the fragment transaction.
2. *Loaders* - When using loaders then in its *onLoadFinished* method I still have the same problems as in (1) but I also need to perform the fragment transaction in a *Handler*, otherwise I get another *IllegalStateException* that indicates that fragment transactions cannot be done in the *onLoadFinished* method.

Basically the result is that currently there is a lot of workarounds that need to be done to make sure that the Android lifecycle is in the "correct" state before performing any operation in an async callback. Even if it means that this library needs to delay the callback invocation until the activity becomes resumed.

What I'm looking for is a library that will make sure that when the async callback is being invoked the corresponding activity is already in the right state and I don't need to do any manual checks and can just go ahead with the fragment transaction or other stuff I want to do.

Goes without saying that it should correctly account for lifecycle events triggered during rotation.

Do you guys know any library that does that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: why "right" is in bold?

Comment: I'm providing here a real concrete problem that Android developers are facing, and providing here what I tried so far (see (1) and (2)), and I'm getting a -4? Seriously?

I have to say that it doesn't really promote a feel good/safe environment to ask questions in, which is the basis of what StackOverflow represents. Would it matter that I replace the word library with the word solution?

Comment: removed the bold for the "right" word.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what code you choose to use you're going to need to be lifecycle aware. That is to say you're always going to have to check your fragments and activities are in the right state before performing fragment transactions. In the loader case you can check the state and then use commitAllowingStateLoss instead of commit, which will eliminate the need for a handler.

But this should only be done after assuring that the fragment you're transitioning from is still active. Unfortunately there isn't currently a straightforward way to setup up a workflow that when a network call is successful you transition to the next screen or fragment.